# PDO Extension on Laravel unit testing

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing

I've been struggling with setting up unit test with my Laravel application, I'm facing error... it says that PDO extension is not installed and giving me error that "PDOException driver not found" but it's installed!!!. When I serve my application everything is OK!!!

PDO is also installed:

```
  28 => "json"
  29 => "exif"
  30 => "mysqli"
  31 => "pdo_mysql"
  32 => "pdo_sqlite"
  33 => "Phar"
  34 => "posix"
  35 => "readline"
  36 => "shmop"
```

Here is my test code:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Models\User\User;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        factory(User::class)->create();
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Trace of error:

```
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:624
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:459
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:411
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php:32
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2653
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:1347
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:835
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:800
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:663
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:206
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:419
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:207
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:181
 /home/soheil/Documents/Projects/PHP/EcollegeMe/tests/Unit/ExampleTest.php:18

 Caused by
 PDOException: could not find driver
```

Comment: How do you run your tests?

Comment: i'm runing my tests with phpstorm!
everything is ok when i run `./vendor/bin/phpunit` command

Comment: Put some phpinfo call in your unit tests and run it. I think, it uses the wrong version

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have pdo extension enable on cli you can do this by running `php -m` on your terminal.

Make sure you load the pdo extension in both cli and fpm mode

EDIT: you can check which configuration file is used from the command line by running `php -i`

Comment: In other words what you are saying is that there may be a separate `php.ini` file. (often named `php-cli.ini`) - which is something I know, but it's not entirely clear in your answer.  In any case it's possible even likely that `cli.ini` does not have PDO enabled...  So, it would be my guess as well.  (this was something I learned due to Timezone settings, the hard way... lol)

Comment: That's not lack of PDO extension, but lack of the mysql or sqlite extension.